# Prologで繰り返し処理を行う方法

Tags: prolog

下に示したのは、表(或いは行列)形式で与えられたデータをcsvファイル形式で書き出すプログラムです。

ここでappend/3を使うのはfailでの失敗駆動を避けるためですが、少し不自然な感じがします。
どのように改良したら、もっと分り易いコードになるでしょうか。

```
put_csv_lines(_csvファイル,_区切り符号,LL) :-  
tell(_csvファイル),  
一行ずつ表示する(LL),  
told.  

一行ずつ表示する(LL) :-  
append(_,[L|R],LL),  
concat_atom(L,_区切り符号,_行表示),  
writef('%t\n',[_行表示]),  
R = [].
```

ここで append/3 が使われている主な理由は最後の副目標 R = [] で全ての行が終了した時点で
述語も真で終わりたいからです。その問題がなければ、member/2 で良い筈です。

```
一行ずつ表示する(Outstream,LL) :-  
member(L,LL),  
concat_atom(L,_区切り符号,_行表示),  
swritef(_改行付き行表示,'%t\n',[_行表示]),  
write(Outstream,_改行付き行表示),  
fail.  
一行ずつ表示する(_,_).
```

このスタイルを嫌ったのが上記の append/3 を使った定義ということになります。さて、他に
これに代わる表現はないでしょうか？

Comment: より適切なタイトル付けと、マークアップを行ってはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 読みやすくなるよう編集しました。他の質問も、コードはコードとして、質問文は見出しではなく本文として読めるよう体裁を整えていただいた方が読みやすく、さらには回答もつきやすくなると思います。また、どのあたりが不自然と考えているかを具体化すると、改善策を提示しやすくなると思います。

Comment: entoさん、済みません。時間的に、変更が重なってしまったようです。Prologでも当たり前の字下げがされていないのは、私の流儀で、将来Prologをこのようなものにしたいと思っているからです。それで、この姿で押し通すことをお許しください。

Comment: コードブロック内の字下げも変えてしまっていましたか。今後気をつけますね。

Answer (score 2):

質問者としてコメントします。
forall/2 を使ったら良いのではないか？という回答を期待しました。
期待通りの回答を戴いたということになります。

上で回答者に対するコメントとして書いたことですが、読みにくいので書き直します。
失敗駆動と呼ばれるコード

```
foo(L) :-  
  member(A,L),
  writef('%t\n',[A]),
  fail.
foo(_).
```

これを forall/2 を使って、

```
foo(L) :-  
  forall(member(A,L),writef('%t\n',[A])).
```

とすっきりと書き直す話です。
forall(P,Q) はPが真になる全ての場合にQもまた真である。という意味です。
Pが真である場合にQが偽になると、forall/2 自体がfailしてしまいます。
forall/2はPとQの間に上記の関係が成立しています。あるいは、関係を検査する述語である
とも言えます。
ところが、上記の例では、このように関係を規定する述語を手続き的な連接を表現するのに利用
しています。
それで構わないと考えて私も好んでこの表現を使うのですが、留意点があります。それは、
Q側に分割された部分に上のコードでいうと、failまで到達しないケースがあってはならない。
ここでは、 writef/2　のみですから、これが真になりfailに到達することは自明ですが、
Qのコードが大きかったり、複雑だったり、あるいはExceptionを含むコードである場合には
failまで到達していないケースがありうるのではないかと疑い、これを潰して置く必要が
あります。

Answer (score 1):

forall/2とmember/2を組み合わせて繰り返し処理を行うことができます。

```
save_as_csv_file(File, Separator, Table) :-
    open(File, write, Out),
    forall(member(Row, Table),
           write_csv_line(Out, Separator, Row)),
    close(Out),
    !.

write_csv_line(Out, Separator, Row) :-
    concat_atom(Row, Separator, Line),
    swritef(LineNL, '%t\n', [Line]),
    write(Out, LineNL).
```

この書き方では、TableのそれぞれのメンバーRowに対してwrite_csv_lineの処理を行うことが、素直に表現できています。

もちろん、これを読む人間はforall/2の使い方を知っていなければ内容を理解できません。しかし失敗駆動を直接使ったループでは、失敗の後どこまでバックトラックするのかをプログラムから読み取るのは容易でなく、プログラムを読む人間に負担を強いることになります。

Comment: 済みません以下、うまく改行しません。後で直します。  

私好みのforall/2 なのですが、やはり注意が必要と思って載せました。その前に、この質問はswritef/3,writef/2 の並びのような不自然なコードを露悪的に示しているつもりです。SWI-Prologがストリーム出力のwritef/3をサポートして欲しいとの願いを込めて。

さて、forall/2ですが、
元々 p(A,R),q(A),R=[].のようなコードを

    ?- forall(p(A),q(A)).  
    
変換した場合、q(A),が必ず真になり、R=[]に到達している必要があります。コードを置き換える場合、この保証をどのようにして得るかが問題になります。「手続き的」なコードは一般にタスクが大きくなりコードも長くなります。これまでfailしてしまう部分があっても放置されている場合はあり得ます。どこでExceptionが発生する可能性があるか掴み難いということもあります。
最初の失敗駆動的なコードをどう、p,qに分割するかということを含めて注意するべき点は多いように思います。

Comment: 自分なりの回答があるのであれば、別の回答として投稿してください。

Comment: 願いを込めながら文章やコードを書かれても、読む側は困惑してしまいます。質問者は何が問題であると考えているのかが分かるように、質問を修正していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: swritefを経由する問題は古典的な tell/1 told/0 を使えばもっとすっきりします。
載せてから大分経つけれど、変えてしまっていいのだろうか。